# (VS2015) Attempting to fill a static map with data from initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, list-initialization

I have a class sorta like:

```
class Object {
public:
    struct Flag {
        const uint32_t bit = 0;
        const wchar_t* name = L"";
        const wchar_t sign = L"";
    }

    static std::map<const char*, Flag> Flags;
}
```

I'm currently on VS2015, but want to support clang and gcc (the latest). My problem is, I can't figure out how to actually initialize that map with data.

I tried putting it inline, like:

```
static std::map<const char*, Flag> Flags = {
    { "FOO1",       { 0, L"FOO1",       L'A' } },
    { "FOO2",       { 1, L"FOO3",       L'B' } },
    { "FOO3",       { 2, L"FOO3",       L'C' } }
}
```

But that complained that only const integral types can be in-class. Okay! So I just left it as the declaration in the class definition (as shown in the first code snippet), and put this in the associated cpp:

```
static std::map<const char*, Object::Flag> Object::Flags = {
    { "FOO1",       { 0, L"FOO1",       L'A' } },
    { "FOO2",       { 1, L"FOO3",       L'B' } },
    { "FOO3",       { 2, L"FOO3",       L'C' } }
}
```

Now this complains that:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::map,std::allocator>>'
```

The thing is, I could've **sworn** I've had this working, so I'm thinking I must have the syntax wrong. If not, clearly I'm missing how to load a static map into a classes namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++11 standard, `Flag` is not an aggregate due to the presence of the brace-or-equal-initializers (aka default member initializers), so attempting to use aggregate initialization to initialize it fails. C++14 [removed this restriction](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html), so `Flag` is considered an aggregate according to that version of the standard, and [your code is valid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f13f4e33da7b21f).

Here's a much simpler version of your example that fails to compile with `-std=c++11`, but successfully compiles with `-std=c++14`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct Flag {
    const uint32_t bit = 0;
    const wchar_t* name = L"";
    const wchar_t sign = L' ';
};

int main()
{
    Flag f{ 0U, L"FOO1", L'A' };
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe6fed36d5e4376).

VS2015 still has the C++11 behavior, so your options are to either remove the default member initializers (thus making `Flag` an aggregate), or provide a constructor for `Object::Flag`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot initialize an object of `Object::Flag` by using the list initialization syntax, `{ 0, L"FOO1",       L'A' }` since it has default member initializers. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization for more details.

You cannot use aggregate initialization of the form

```
Object::Flag f = { 0, L"FOO1", L'A'};
```

for the same reason. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization.

Change `Object::Flag` to the simpler form of:

```
struct Flag {
    const uint32_t bit;
    const wchar_t* name;
    const wchar_t sign;
};
```

and then you should be able to use:

```
std::map<const char*, Object::Flag> Object::Flags = {
   { "FOO1", { 0, L"FOO1", L'A' } },
   { "FOO2", { 1, L"FOO3", L'B' } },
   { "FOO3", { 2, L"FOO3", L'C' } }};
```

After that, you should be able to also use:

```
Object::Flag f = { 0, L"FOO1", L'A'};
```

Comment: This is not true anymore with C++14 I think (looks like VS is a bit late).

Comment: This link can complement yours I think: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: @Holt, it sure does. Thanks for the suggestion.